# Which word in the dictionary is spelled wrong?

Tags: riddle

What is the only word that is spelled wrong in the dictionary?

Comment: Welcome to puzzling. This doesn't seem like a riddle to me, as it's pretty straightforward. Please read about the riddle tag and also about [riddles on meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox)

Comment: @ABcDexter okay, what do you think is a suitable tag for it, It is a riddle maybe very simple one , but it is one.

Answer (score 8):

Are you thinking about the word:

> "wrong" itself?